# Hive query giving incorrect output

Tags: shell, hive, bigdata

I'm facing this issue where the hive query is giving the output :
Last cycle cut for US: hive.exec.stagingdir=.hive-staging
2022-10-27

But the correct output should be :
Last cycle cut for US: 2022-10-27.

Query being used -

```
cycle_cut=$(hive -e "set mapred.job.queue.name=test;SET hive.cli.print.header=false;
```

;SELECT '2022-10-27'");
echo " Last cycle cut for US: $cycle_cut "

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is use the silent mode. Add "-S" in the command.

eg : `hive -S -e "SELECT '2022-10-27'"`

You can get more info from: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+cli

And about the info "hive.exec.stagingdir", Maybe because you did not set the hive.exec.stagingdir, so the client will use the default settings, and print that on terminal.

```
<property>
    <name>hive.exec.stagingdir</name>
    <value>.hive-staging</value>
</property>
```

Maybe you can try to add the settings in your query

```
"SET hive.exec.stagingdir=/tmp/"
```

eg: `cycle_cut=$(hive -e "set mapred.job.queue.name=test;SET hive.cli.print.header=false;SET hive.exec.stagingdir=/tmp/;SELECT '2022-10-27'"); echo " Last cycle cut for US: $cycle_cut "`

I`m not sure it work or not ,Looking forward to your feedback!

Comment: Hi M-chen,
Thanks for your time and answer. I tried using this, but i'm getting a failure message to my query.